# Java Calendar: How to move calendar to next month using JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I'm fairly new to GUI and events but can you enlighten me? Do I make a new JFrame for each month? or a JPanel? I need to make a Calendar with a full month view on each window, and if I click next button, it will go to the next month. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the calender GUI I found what works best for me is using a different Jpanel for each month and putting each month on a tabbed pane and naming it the correct month. I have seen it before in others applications and I find it looks nice and it is easy to go from a month like December to August without having to click a button Five times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! SO what Layout should I use? Card Layout? Also, I need to make a calendar 5 years ago and 5 years from now. So I need many Panels for them :(

Comment: Are you making a program or is this using Html?

Comment: I use a basic java compiler. I need it for my finals. yes, a basic calendar program that spans 5 years before and 5 years from now.

Comment: Ok, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html that is a great link that tells you have to use tabbed panes. Basically what you need to do is put a calender month or year on 1 pane the add it to the tabbed pane. If done correctly you will have a month or year on each tab

Comment: So let me get this straight, let's say 1 tab is 1 month. and I have 12 tabs. How can I make another 12 tabs for the past year? I'm still confused but your idea seems to be very good. I like your GUI idea.

Comment: If your are not to far in your project you should get this create program called netbeans. I has a GUI creator built into the program that allows you to drag different components right into the JFrame and not even have to think about the code. It has the newest swing components and I think works great!

Comment: Nice. Just what I needed. I was too focused on the manual GUI building. THANKS MATE!

Answer (score 0):

I would populate a JPanel with the data needed, when I needed it, rather than switching JPanel all the time. You're going to populate a JPanel with the data needed anyway, and you don't want to do it manually. If you want a quicker way to go from one month to a one 6 months later, I would just provide the user with a view similar to that of the Windows calendar (lower right corner) and have them pick a month, and then populate the JPanel with the information about this month.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! But how exactly do I travel from one panel to another using JButton?